# AppleScript to switch on Remote Management and turn on VNC

Tags: macos, applescript, system-preferences

I'm just wondering if anyone could help me develop an AppleScript programme to be able to tick all the boxes like seen on here https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT1WS.jpg as well as be able to tick the VNC box and type in a password, like seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP1Mc.jpg

I tried to look at other already made programmes and found this code made by Gordon Davisson.

```
do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -restart -agent -privs -all" with administrator privileges
```

I am wondering if anyone could develop it further to add the features I want onto it.

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Safe to assume you mean the "VNC" password box (not the "VPN") box? Are you against using UI with System Events scripting?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. I would rather have this program do everything

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `-clientopts -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes -setvncpw -vncpw 'YourPasswordHere'` in the `-configure` section of the command options. Here's what it should look like:

```
do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -privs -all -clientopts -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes -setvncpw -vncpw 'YourPasswordHere' -restart -agent" with administrator privileges
```

Note that kickstart's option syntax is weirdly hierarchical. Here I've attempted to diagram the structure of that command's sections, subsections, etc:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart
    -activate
    -configure
        -access -on
        -privs -all
        -clientopts
            -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes
            -setvncpw -vncpw 'CorrectHorseBatteryStaple'
    -restart -agent
```

See the man page [here](http://ss64.com/osx/kickstart.html).